# How to get reference of jquery noConflict() dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are developing a app which will give livechat service in the websites.

We are including a js file to the websites. We have used snack.js framework to perform DOM operations(since it is small and enough flexible to our needs).

The problem is,
if site contains jquery file, snack is not working properly and it returns unrelavent results. To avoid this we are using jquery functions if webpage has jquery. 
But when website page has multiple jquery files, they are using noConflict() method to avoid version conflict. Here we are not getting the reference of the jquery($ and jquery not working here) to perform operations on the DOM.

## For Ex:

var conflictjquery = jQuery.noConflict(); --- Done by site developers.

How to get this "conflictjquery" variable to my js works ?

Can you suggest on this if we have any possibility.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation suggest it : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

You must do like this :

```
var myJQuery = $.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing `$.noConflict();` does is releasing the global `$` variable. This means the library can still be used through the `jQuery` variable.

Considerer the following example:

```
<script src="jquery1.js"></script>
<script>$.noConflict();</script>
<script src="jquery2.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery; //use jquery1
    $; //use jquery2
</script>
```

However if the `$` is already used by another library on the page and you are trying to
load two different jQuery versions on top of this it will not work. In that case you need
to move the main `jQuery` namespace into a whole new object.

You can do it like:

```
var dom = {};

dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

You could then use it like:

```
dom.query(...);
```